# Do I need to user schemamigration and migrate commands after changing a field name or a field data type in a model?

Tags: python, django

The problem is pretty self-explanatory in the title. Do I need to do that or I just need to edit the existing migration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Django won't recognize the field if you change the name.  I will say that the "field does not exist", so YES, you have to run Django's South `migrate` / `schemamigration` as you asked.

Datatype YES as well.  Django may be okay at first if you only change the field type depending, but may run into problems later depending on what you have in that field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a schemamigration every time you change your models.

On every call of python manage.py migrate command `south` record number of the latest migration applied into database `migrationhistory` table. So if you just change existing migration it won't be applied because south would think it's already applied.

You can make a backward migration, fix next migration, even delete it and make a new one and only then migrate forward.